# GSON problem in android 2.3.3

Tags: android, serialization, gson

I am having trouble serializing to JSON via GSON . Here is my Poll class

```
package com.impact.datacontracts;

public class Poll {

public int FeedID;
public int Answer;
public Poll(){}
}
```

I am serializing like this

```
public void submitPoll(int answerID, int feedID) {
    Poll poll = new Poll();
    poll.Answer = answerID;
    poll.FeedID = feedID;

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonString = gson.toJson(poll);
    Toast.makeText(_context, jsonString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

in Android 2.2 i get Toast as:

```
{"FeedID":"1","Answer":"1"}
```

which is correct , while the same code produces this Toast in Android 2.3.3 :

```
{"FeedID":"0","Answer":"0"}
```

but if i change the datatype of FeedID and Answer to String  then it works fine in 2.3.3 , i can live with Strings but what could be wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying this out on an HTC device? If yes, you might be a victim of [this](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-on-android). Test your app on a vanilla Android device (such as a Nexus One / S or on an emulator). If the problem disappears, you know it was the device's fault and you can easily repackage GSON by following the steps on the aforementioned page.

Comment: i am checking on Samsung Galaxy S

Comment: i just repackaged the Gson jar to a new name, same trouble :( , i am unable to test on Android 2.3.3 emulator as it fails to register javascriptlistner.

Comment: Maybe the IDs are screwed up in the first place? Try including `answerID` and `feedID` in the `Toast` as well, see if they match.